# How to create an Array which contains unduplicated and not random numbers?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tree

I want to create a method in JavaScript which can generate an array containing non-random and non-duplicate numbers by using Tree structure.

Assuming the method named `permutation()`, I just simply use

```
permutation(3)
```

and I will get an array which can iterate and each of them is

```
012 021 120 102 201 210
```

if I change the number 3 to 5 , it will generate an Array

```
012345 012354 etc...
```

and then I figure out I can use tree structure to build this kind of array like this:

```
root:     0      1      2 
        ↓   ↓  ↓   ↓  ↓   ↓
depth1: 1   2  0   2  1   0
        ↓   ↓  ↓   ↓  ↓   ↓
depth2: 2   1  1   0  0   1
```

then I just traverse all the nodes to get the result.

It's same when the number is increased

```
root:           0               1   2   3   4   5   6....
        ↓   ↓   ↓   ↓   ↓   ↓
depth1: 1   2   3   4   5   6

etc....
```

The question is I don't know how could I construct such a tree in JavaScript? I don't know what kind of these questions named.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permutations in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960908/permutations-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You could take the array and get a sub tree for every leftover items.

```js
function createTree(array) {
    return array.map((v, i, a) => array.length === 1
        ? [v]
        : [v, createTree([...a.slice(0, i), ...a.slice(i + 1)])]
    );
}

var result = createTree([0, 1, 2]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```